# Scoping a CSS stylesheet to only one DIV via Nested Classes

Tags: javascript, css, nested, less

I'm trying to display a website's content (preview) inside an admin interface. Thet requires the entire CSS stylesheet for the content (website) to be applied to the .preview DIV in the admin interface. The website.css file is not always the same as it depends which website is being previewed.

I' trying to use LESS.JS and Nested Rules but it will not work with Inline styles. I'm on a windows platform.

```
<style>
.preview {
  <- Dynamically loading Website.css file content here ->
}
</style>
```

Problem is that LESS.JS will not act on inline styles. I'd like to keep the website.css file intact.

I could load the website.css, add the extra class, rename it to .less and write it back to the folder, and link the .less file... but it seems a bit too much for something so simple...

Comment: You can't really scope CSS. It works on specificity, not DOM scope.

Comment: Could you not just host an image preview? (Like Google)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, ended up using LESS.JS which is pretty well suited for this task. I wrapped the Website.css file in a .class of the container DIV.

Less.JS compiles the CSS and adds the .class in front of all definitions, wich does the trick. – mfr just now edit

```
@*LESS.JS CSS*@
<style type="text/less" >
    .preview  
    {
        @File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(DesignHelper.GetTemplateFileName("Website.css")))
    } 
</style>
```

Notice the 'less' in  `<style type="text/less" >`